# Deposition in epioceanic areas

Tags: sedimentology

I found allochthonous (I don´t know the 2 locations) fined grained
carbonate sediment in Ammonitico Rosso, which is possibly mudstone in
the South Iberian Peninsule, specifically in Carcabuey (Córdoba). It is
known that this sediment was formed in the Kimmeridgian and the area was
located in epioceanic shelf, upper waters/mixed layer. There are several
bioclasts in a good state of preservation, so it was covered quickly
enough (high deposition rate) to avoid dissolution. It is not
possible to know how much, I just have a hand sample from the field.
With this information: How can we explain these factors happen together?
- Fine grained sediment, so low energy - high deposition rate -
allochthonous carbonates - good state of preservation of bioclasts

If you need more information to try to answer this question, please let
me know.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

A [turbidity current](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Historical_Geology/Turbidites) can easily account for what you've observed. It could be part of a repetitive sequence of shallow angle sloughs caused by accumulating overburden, much like the Bouma Sequences that make up a Turbidite Deposit, or it could be a one-time gravity flow caused by an earthquake.